# bootstrap 3 datepicker not showing calendar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap 3 in my code,but its not working.Where am I going wrong,please help me out.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">
  </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input  type="text">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main input").datepicker();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you repeating your jquery.js and bootstrap.js? Use only one time and at the bottom of the page before your closing body tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a id to the input field

```
<input id="dp" type="text">
```

and in jquery

```
<script src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dp').datepicker();
});
</script>
```